# What happens if the user closes an app that is already in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, appdelegate

During a background task execution what will happen if the user kills the app (which already is in background mode)?

Picture this:

The app starts task X (with 10 min background support and a expiration handler that has to be called).
Then, the app goes to background and the user kills the app.

I'm confused on what will happen to task X after the app is killed. Does it still have that background time to execute? Does the expiration handler ever gets called?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted, but isn't it pretty simple to test this yourself?

Comment: Interesting question. The docs are unclear on this. Try it. Let us know what actually happens. I'd be curious if the `applicationWillTerminate` `UIApplicationDelegate` method is called in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the app is "already in background", the user has *already* "closed the app"! So what can your question mean? You've already gone into the background, and if you called `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` as you did so, things proceed normally.

Do you mean the user forcibly kills the app in the background, by summoning the "recent apps" interface and going into jiggy mode and deleting the app from the "recent apps" interface? Then the app is summarily killed; you get no notification and whatever you were doing is interrupted.

Moreover, the only thing the expiration handler block is supposed to do is call `endBackgroundTask:`. If you are summarily killed, the fact that you are unable to make this call is unimportant!

Comment: You got it. But it is important to get the expirationHandler called, I have code there that has to be executed.

Comment: Then you have designed the expiration handler incorrectly. All the expiration handler should do is call `endBackgroundTask:`. The expiration handler means your background task time has expired; you have no time to do anything except acknowledge this and get out. If you fail to do that, your app will not be suspended - it will be killed dead.

Comment: Another worry here is the notion "I have code ... that has to be executed". Nothing is guaranteed, sorry. Your architecture needs to accept that.

Comment: As Matt says, your architecture must accept it. What would you do if the device were turned off or crashed or were dropped in a lake? Future code execution is never certain. `SIGKILL` is just one of many things that can happen to you.

Comment: Ohhhhh I SEE!!! So Ok I did misunderstood what that expiration handler was all about! (anyway... why can't the system just invalidate the backgroundtask ids my app uses?) Thanks matt and Rob Napier !

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12663976/341994 When @bbum talks, you should listen. You absolutely cannot guarantee that any code of yours will run at termination. "Your code absolutely must be hardened against unexpected termination."

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to test, so I just did (on an iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3) using code I'll paste at the end, which starts a background task in the app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground` method.
The result is surprising.
When the user exits the app by clicking the Home button, then manually kills the app (by double-clicking Home, putting things in jiggy mode and hitting the app's close icon) the following occurs:

1. `applicationWillTerminate` is called.
2. When `applicationWillTerminate` exits, background execution is terminated, regardless of how much execution time the background task had left. The app has been killed.

**HOWEVER..**

If you arrange things so that `applicationWillTerminate` doesn't exit after being called, as in my code below, the following happens -- at least it does on my test setup -- when the app is manually killed:

1. The app's background task **continues to run in the background**.
2. Even when the allocated background execution time has expired, the background task continues to run, as does the code in `applicationWillTerminate`, until that method exits.

This is clearly a bug -- you shouldn't be able to continue to run code forever -- and I wouldn't rely on it always working. But those who've been using various hacks around playing audio in the background to keep an app alive might want to investigate. I'd be interested if other people try the code on different iOS versions/devices and get the same results.

Code for AppDelegate.m in my test project:

```
//
//  BTAppDelegate.m
//  BackgroundTest
//
//  Created by David Fearon on 07/05/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 David Fearon. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BTAppDelegate.h"

@implementation BTAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called");
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillResignActive: called");

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground: called");


    UIApplication* thisApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier __block task = [thisApp beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self printTimeRemaining];
        while(YES) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
            [self printTimeRemaining];
        }
        //[thisApp endBackgroundTask:task];
    });

}


-(void)printTimeRemaining{
    NSLog(@"Background task time remaining: %f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground: called");

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive: called");

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate: called");

    while(YES) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
        NSLog(@"Still executing code in applicationWillTerminate.");
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: The apple app store review team probably runs a test to check that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this is the result

**In this case OS will send a SIGKILL signal to your app's process and applicationWillTerminate method is not called.**

Below is just my interpretation from Apple docs, guess work and Google results.

In such case below method of your application delegate will get called

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Quote from Apple Docs

> For applications that do not support background execution or are
>   linked against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when
>   the user quits the application. For applications that support
>   background execution, this method is generally not called when the
>   user quits the application because the application simply moves to the
>   background in that case. **However, this method may be called in
>   situations where the application is running in the background (not
>   suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason.**

So you have to UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend value to YES in your plist file otherwise there is no guarantee that applicationWillTerminate: will ever get called. That is why the doc has *may* used in.

I dont think expiration handler block will be called, though I am not sure.

Comment: Is this confirmed? The docs for the method are vague. It's seems clear that this delegate method is called if your app support one of the proper `UIBackgroundModes`. But it's not clear is this delegate is called if your app is killed by the user while in the background while the app is inside a `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`.

Comment: The quote from the docs is the unclear information I mentioned. To me, those docs aren't clear on whether the delegate is called or not in this case. Someone needs to actually try this - any takers? I'm head out the door for a while otherwise I'd give it a shot.

Comment: I believe it's not guaranteed that system will call applicationWillTerminate

Comment: An application receiving `SIGKILL` immediately dies. It does not and cannot run any additional code. It cannot catch the signal. It cannot ignore the signal. It is unceremoniously tossed. UIKit (let alone your code) doesn't get a chance to do anything about it, because it happens at the OS layer.

Comment: Note that this isn't actually vague. The response to `SIGKILL` is part of the POSIX definition going back decades. UIKit is only documenting behaviors within its control, and `SIGKILL` happens outside its control. For more details if you want them, you can see the `sigaction(2)` man page. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man2/sigaction.2.html